# On click with multiple events

Tags: onclick

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CB6" name="" value=""  onclick="return KeepCount2(); ShowReg(6)">
```

It doesn't seem to work for me can someone correct this please =)

It does the keepcount but doesn't do the showreg.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot the semicolon plus, the first one includes return

Answer (score 2):

The `ShowReg(6)` isn't called because you've got the `return` just be `KeepCount2()`, thus the flow stops there. Check to see if you don't what to write instead:

```
 onclick="KeepCount2(); return ShowReg(6);"
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="KeepCount2(); ShowReg(6)"`